# Add and delete value from an array in react dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have multiple buttons in react, once I click on the button, its value is  saved in an array. I want, when I click on any button that its value is saved only once, after click on that button again the value should be removed from an array.

e.g.

When I press "click 1" button the array value should be `["1"]` and change the button color, after second click it should be removed.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'; 
const UserDetails = () => {
const [selecthostingOption,setselecthostingOption] = useState([]);

console.log(selecthostingOption);


const hostingChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = e.target.value
  setselecthostingOption(selecthostingOption => [
    ...selecthostingOption,value
  ])

}   
return(
<>
   <button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" value="1">Click 1</button>
   <button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" value="2">Click 2</button>

</>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value if already in selections,

```
const hostingChange = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = e.target.value;

  if (selecthostingOption.includes(value)) {
    setselecthostingOption(selecthostingOption.filter(x => x !== value));
  } else {
    setselecthostingOption([...selecthostingOption, value]);
  }
};
```

Change both button styles based on selections

```
<button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" style={{
    color: selecthostingOption.includes("1") 'red' : ''
  }} value="1">Click 1</button>
```

Comment: how to make it dynamic please. Like  selecthostingOption.includes("1") in this line, can i make it dynamic instead of static includes. @Siva Kondapi Venkata

Comment: @AdnanArif, Yes, you can do that. like `['1', '2'].map(id => (<button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" style={{
    color: selecthostingOption.includes(id) 'red' : ''
  }} value={id}>`Click ${id}</button>)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array for something like this. Use an object:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; 

const UserDetails = () => {
  const [hostingOptions, setHostingOptions] = useState({});

  const hostingChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const value = e.target.value
    setHostingOptions(!!hostingOptions[value])
  }

  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" value="1">Click 1</button>
      <button onClick={hostingChange} name="selecthostingOption" value="2">Click 2</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Then how I will get all values from same name options.

Comment: In your example, they have different values (1 and 2).